# $(this) inside tabled td is returning undefined

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a table with a cell:

```
<td>
<i class="fa fa-trash-o trashIcon ng-scope" 
aria-hidden="true" 
ng-click="DeleteRow(jQuery(this));"></i>
</td>
```

When the function DeleteRow is called, elementToDelete is undefined:

[image]

Why is jQuery(this) not returning `<i>` element?

Comment: You should use `$event.currentTarget`/ `$event.target` instead of `this`

Comment: Try this I guess it will help you, `ng-click="DeleteRow(this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `$event` in the ng-click angularjs

```
<td><i class="fa fa-trash-o trashIcon ng-scope" 
aria-hidden="true" 
ng-click="DeleteRow($event);"></i>
</td>


$scope.DeleteRow = function(event) {
  console.log($(event.target));
  jquery(event.target).remove()
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/akgx7Lqu/22/)**

Comment: is there a problem with sign $ if I use jQuery and angularJs at the same time? Is sign $ used by jQuery or angular if used inside angularjs controller?

Comment: Then use jquery(event.target)

Comment: Glad it helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

pass `$event` in your function

```
<td>
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o trashIcon ng-scope" 
     aria-hidden="true" ng-click="DeleteRow($event);">Delete
    </i>
</td>
```

use `$event.currentTarget` to select the current selected element

```
$scope.DeleteRow = function($event) {
    $event.currentTarget.remove();
}
```

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/akgx7Lqu/21/)

Answer (score 0):

i think you bind this td by ng-repeat so during this you just place the same object in the ng-click: suppose :

```
   <div ng-repeat="set_listing in get_listing">
    <div class="width_hun">

            <p class="item_name" ng-click="DeleteRow(set_listing)"></p>


    </div>
</div>
```

then you can access your current event easily